# When does the remainder term in the taylor series go to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

When does the remainder term in the taylor series go to zero?

**Theorem**: Let $f\in C^{N+1}([\alpha,\beta])$ and $x,x_0\in(\alpha,\beta)$. Then

$$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{1}{2}f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2+...+\frac{f^{(N)}(x_0)}{N!}(x-x_0)^N+\frac{(x-x_0)^{N+1}}{N!}\int_0^1 (1-t)^Nf^{(N+1)}(x_0+t(x-x_0))dt$$

Where the remainder term, $R_N$, is

$$R_N=\frac{(x-x_0)^{N+1}}{N!}\int_0^1 (1-t)^Nf^{(N+1)}(x_0+t(x-x_0))dt$$

I'm really not understanding this concept, especially because I'm struggling to comprehend what $R_N$ actually means.

Comment: I suppose when the series converges. Does that make any sense ?

Comment: I've the remainder term converges to zero, then the entire series will converge to whatever function we are approximating. But when will the remainder term converge to zero?

Comment: I don't think that answers the question. When the remainder converges to zero, $f$ is analytic at $x_0$. But when will the remainder converge to zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy answer to the question of how to prove that the remainder term goes to zero. It is an art. The art of bounds, the mathematical art known as "Analysis".

If you try some examples you may begin to develop a mastery at this art. For instance, try $f(x) = \cos(x)$. The absolute value of the integrand is 
$$\bigl| \, (1-t)^Nf^{(N+1)}(x_0+t(x-x_0)) \, \bigr|
$$
This is easy to bound. Since all derivatives of $\cos(x)$ are just $\pm\sin(x)$ or $\pm\cos(x)$, and since $0 \le t \le 1$, it follows that the integrand is $\le 1$ in absolute value, for all $t$. So, integrating between $0$ and $1$, and using that $\bigl| \int (blah) \bigr| \le \int |blah|$, we get
$$|R_N| \le \frac{|x-x_0|^{N+1}}{N!}
$$
Since $|x-x_0|$ is independent of $N$, this comes down to a standard limit problem that you should know from calculus, namely 
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} a^N/N!=0
$$

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thank you!

Comment: Just to note: here you can see the general fact that $|R_n| \leq {|x-x_0|}^{N+1}$ I was pointing at. Kudos, excellent explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind Taylor series is to approximate an $N+1$-times continuously differentiable function at a point by using the information given by the derivatives at that point. For example, when a function is differentiable and its derivative is continuous, we can give a linear approximation of this function at any point. This is the first order Taylor approximation.

Of course we cannot reconstruct the whole function (say, $f$) from it's Taylor approximation of any finite order, since information about $f$ is lost. In particular, when a function is not infinitely differentiable, we only have the Taylor approximation available up to a certain order (namely, $N$). The remainder represents the lost information, and can be defined precisely. However Taylor's theorem states that the higher the order of the approximation, the more negligible the remainder is, when close to the point of approximation, $x_0$. Technically, this can be stated precisely using orders of convergence.

Comment: This helps my general understanding of the Taylor Series, thank you.

Comment: It is a pleasure. Feel free to ask other questions to broaden even more your understanding.

Comment: Can't we just compute the remainder term? If that converges to zero, then the taylor series converges to the function we're attempting to approximate?

Comment: The Taylor formula is defined (or should I say, "Talyor"-made?) in such a way that the remainder always converges to 0 as $x \to x_0$. When adding orders of approximation however, you increase the order of convergence of the remainder. Precisely, when you have an $N$th order Taylor approximation as $x \to x_0$, the remainder converges to 0 as faster than ${|x-x_0|}^N$. Edit: Sorry, the formula was wrong. I corrected it.

Comment: In our lectures we were told that the remainder term doesn't always converge to zero. Also, I like the "Taylor-made" pun!

Comment: Well I am a bit surprised by that, since this contradicts _my_ lectures... Did your teacher give an example of such a function?

Comment: We haven't been given an example. It was a false statement in a class test we did. (We had to find the true statement out of five statements)

Comment: Well the remainder cannot _not_ converge to 0. It represents the approximation error as a function of the distance from the chosen point. If it did not converge to 0, even at precisely the chosen point there would still be an error, which is false by _definition_ of the Taylor series. You might want to check [Taylor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) and [it's proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Proof_for_Taylor.27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The Taylor series is sometimes called a Taylor polynomial. What is the Taylor series of a polynomial function?

Comment: It's the series without the remainder term? i.e the remainder term is zero? But when does it happen?

Comment: Is it always zero? Why is the remainder term zero?

Comment: I don't know, that's my question. When does it go to zero?

Comment: I've misunderstood your question. I thought you asked, when **is** the remainder term zero. The correct answer is given in the original comments. See also the wikipedia page on [analytic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function).

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help.